# Query not giving result in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ipad, sqlite, ios7

I am using sqlite in my application and have a query that is working fine in iOS 6/ iOS 5 but not giving the result in iOS 7 The query is:

```
 Select `user_name`, `user_udid`, `id_ipad` from tablename WHERE user_id ='%@' AND id_ipad = 1 LIMIT 0,1",[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]]
```

and In it

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

returns the correct value.

I there any changes done in SQlite database for iOS 7?
Or Some Methods get depricated..?
or .. Is there is any special character used in the query not to be used for iOS 7..?

Please help

Comment: First of all did you check the parameters?

Comment: yes I have checked..If the prameters are not there.. then it must not work in iOS6.

Comment: How you are using Device UDID?? check `tempDic` before query?

Comment: It returns the correct value.. I am using [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]

Comment: no you're not -- it isnt there on IOS7 and as documented even if you call it in older apps it doesnt even work

Answer (score 1):

The reason is `UIDevice.uniqueIdentifier` has been removed from the `UIDevice` class in iOS 7.

Use the `identifierForVendor` property of this class or the `advertisingIdentifier` property of the `ASIdentifierManager` class instead

For more details, go to [this link.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/uniqueIdentifier)